# List of CDN's for common components/files

Tags: cdn

It seems that the popularity of jQuery and MS AJAX, as well as tools like YSlow & Google Page Speed have given rise to common components being hosted on [Content Delivery Networks (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

So which CDN's exist and what files do they serve?

Answer (score 8):

[Google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) offers a CDN for:

- [jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery)
- [jQuery UI](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jqueryUI)
- [Prototype](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#prototype)
- [script.aculo.us](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#script_aculo_us)
- [MooTools](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#mootools)
- [Dojo](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#dojo)
- [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#swfobject)
- [Yahoo! User Interface Library (YUI)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#yui)
- [Ext Core](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#ext-core)
- [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#chrome-frame)

Comment: Currently Google has no documented support for their CDN over SSL, so if that's a requirement MS is a better choice.

Comment: SSL works now -> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft (Via asp.net)](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn) offers a CDN for:

- [MS Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/#3)
- [jQuery](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/#4)
- [jQuery Validation](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/#5)
- [ASP.NET MVC JavaScript](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/#6)

Comment: MS's CDN also has the ability to serve over SSL

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete list of jquery, jQuery UI and jQuery UI Themes cdn links here at http://jobyj.in/web/jquery-jquery-ui-jquery-ui-themes-cdn-list/

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless, its good project for all non hosted plugin's library over CDN. Many are already using it, you get advantage of lib already in Users browser cache.

[cdncatalog.com](http://cdncatalog.com) list of public CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare hosts a cdn of js libraries http://cdnjs.com/

It is peer reviewed, so you can submit a pull request with a new library: https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers up a CDN for the [jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js).  I believe that that url will always have the most recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

here's one that has some less popular/widespread files:

http://cachedcommons.org/